# UIWebview Returning Blank Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurl

After learning the basic framework, what seems to be working for others is consistently returning a blank screen. Below is what I'm led to believe is overkill, but is still not working. I'm attempting to load an IP as the url (if you are on the same network as one of our products and enter its IP address, a browser will load an interface with relevant values & controls. webIP is the IP string passed from a prior screen and is coming in fine (replacing with google URL still didn't work). This block is inside viewDidLoad in a vanilla [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSCTz.jpg)ViewController:

```
let deviceURL = NSURL(string: "\(webIP)")
    let deviceURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: deviceURL!)
    deviceWebView.loadRequest(deviceURLRequest)
    deviceWebView.reload()
    self.reloadInputViews()
```

I have made sure that there are no UI elements blocking it. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Is there any console log? And did you disable transport security? (e.g.: http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check whether "**App Transport Security Settings**"  entry is  available in plist file?[image]
  If not then add "**App Transport Security Settings**" into your plist file as shown

Comment: Bullseye!! Many thanks.

I also needed to add ' http:// ' to the front of the string as well to get it to work.